# Font Awesome need inverse

Tags: css, font-awesome

Need a help to inverse icon.. I know that I can actually use fa-inverse but how I using this here? 
My css code:

```
hr.style-eight:after {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f0ad";
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative; 
    top: -0.7em;  
    font-size: 1.5em;

    padding: 0 0.25em;
    background:#333333;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: transform:scale(-1); ?  not too clear to me :)

Comment: need change a color, thanks already done

Answer (score 8):

You can flip an element using the following:

```
hr.style-eight:after {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
    transform: scaleX(-1);
    filter: FlipH;
    -ms-filter: "FlipH";
}
```

Comment: but thank you, maybe for next time I will need it :)

Comment: Then I misunderstood what you needed :)

Answer (score 8):

Since FontAwesome is just a Font, all the same rules apply (font-size, color, line-height, etc); so how do you inverse text?

```
body {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```